# Custom useFetch Hook not working after url state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have a single page app that will render two different "Decks" of "Card" components

1. One deck called "ArtistDeck" calls a useFetch hook to return artists
2. Artists are displayed, and when clicking on the artist name,
3. "AlbumDeck" calls a useFetch hook to return albums

In the App component, I have effectively set up two API string states that update correctly. However, when I call the second call that updates the API string to call for albums, the useFetch skips its useEffect hook. I have also verified that the correct URL reaches each call to useFetch.

**Here is the first component that calls useFetch effectively and returns data:**

```
const ArtistDeck = (props) => {
    // props.apiRequest is a correctly formatted api request

    const [apiRequest, setApiRequest] = React.useState("");
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setApiRequest(props.apiRequest);
    }, [props.apiRequest]);

    const apiResult = useFetch(apiRequest);
    // do more stuff
}
```

**And here is the second one that useFetch screws up on:**

```
const AlbumDeck = (props) => {
    // props.apiRequest is a correctly formatted api request
    const [apiRequest, setApiRequest]     = React.useState(props.apiRequest);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setApiRequest(props.apiRequest);
    }, [props.apiRequest]);

    const apiResult = useFetch(apiRequest);    
    // do more stuff
}
```

**Lastly, here is useFetch:**

```
export const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
    React.useEffect( () => {
        console.log("Reached Use Effect");
        const fetchData = async () => {
            console.log("Reached fetchData");
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                console.log("Reached try block");
                const res = await fetch(url);
                console.log("Received res: " + res.statusText);
                const json = await res.json();
                console.log("Received json: " + json);
                setResponse(json);
                setIsLoading(false)
            }
            catch (error) {
                setError(error);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [url]);
    return { response, error, isLoading };
};
```

When debugging, none of the console.log statements trigger, and it just returns the default states. useEffect is skipped. How can I make useEffect work in the second call?

Comment: Any chance you could set this up in a code sandbox or jsfiddle?

Comment: Hey, try to remove `}, [url]);` the url in the useEffect to bo like that `}, []);`